# How make Unity wait before consuming next item in a list?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a class like so:

```
public class SomeObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected List<EdibleStuff> SomeItemsToConsume;

    private void StartConsuming()
    {
        this.SomeItemsToConsume
            .ForEach(item =>
            {
                StartCoroutine(Consume(item));
            });
    }

    private IEnumerator Consume(EdibleStuff edibleStuff)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2);

        // Check whether edibleStuff is still fresh after 2 seconds
        // Figure out how to consume it -- e.g. by cooking, eating raw, whatever
    }
}
```

Before `SomeObject` consumes the next item in the `SomeItemsToConsume` list, I would like it to wait **another** short period of time, say, **another** 2 seconds.

I have tried these approches:

1. I added another `yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2);` statement at the end of the `Consume(EdibleStuff edibleStuff)` method, but that did not work.
2. I added another co-routine, which simply contains the statement `yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2);` in its definition, at the end of the `ForEach` loop, but that did not work either.

How can I achieve the effect I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the **ForEach** inside the coroutine:

```
public class SomeObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    protected List<EdibleStuff> SomeItemsToConsume;

    private IEnumerator Consume()
    {
        this.SomeItemsToConsume
        .ForEach(item =>
        {
            WaitForSecondsRealtime wait = new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2);

            /// Process your item...

            yield return wait; 
        });
    }
}
```

Since what it was done in your **StartConsuming** method was that in your loop a 'n' number of coroutines (being 'n' the count of your list) were being started at the same frame. Having it inside a coroutine makes sure that the List moves to the next element once the WaitForSecondsRealTime's **keepWaiting** property returns true, which is not on the same frame (even if the time passed were 0).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, I do not have access to my repository until next week. Once I verify that your answer works, I will mark it as accepted.